# why devspace command not recognising 'sh.exe' on windows via npm or via powershell?

Tags: windows, kubernetes, npm, sh, devspace

I am trying to install devspace on windows os by following official doc https://www.devspace.sh/docs/getting-started/installation?x0=6

via powershell or with npm, it installed successfully but when I go further to use it by
`devspace versiono` or `devspace init`

it does not work and shows below. I have also enabled Set-ExecutionPolicy and tried setting it to Unrestricted or to RemoteSigned. But does not help.

```
& : The term 'sh.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\devspace.ps1:24 char:7
+     & "sh$exe"  "$basedir/node_modules/devspace/bin/devspace" $args
+       ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sh.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What is missing here? or is there any way out to make it run?

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution? I am figuring the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, not. But I switched my work on Linux and it worked there!